# fedex integration to Magento not showing Discount rate

Tags: magento

My integration with fedex is completed...auth key, meter # ect. Fedex had offered adiscount rate which is already programmed on their side and I can see in my account. However when i do a test, it shows me The LIST rate not the DISCOUNT rate which I want it offered to the clients as well. I need the total net FEDEX charge shown. Another problem is that it is not able to calculate the # of pcs purchased. Example if I bought1 stool the shipping rate is $100 and if i bought 4 stools the shipping cost is the same $100.

My developer seems to give up on this and says i hjust have to use the table> Please rea below what he is saying. I apolgize im not well versed at this. Please HELP ME.

Hi Susan,

After doing  more research  and talking with FedEx tech support executive and Magento  support , I reached at this conclusion. I am describing  the conclusion details below:

When I talked with tech support guy , he said me to contact with Magento team . I had also consult with them and scrutinize the code in programming label.  I got that FedEx is giving only a API access to Magento.  I am making it easy to understand you. FedEx is giving some access to us to get their shipping rates to show on our site. If we make a account specifies, I mean they are giving some discount only on your account or any specified account . FedEx has not developed this(customer specific shipping rates)  type of API , which we’ll use it on micazza.net.

This account specific shipping rates can’t be applied  on website.

It’ll be better if you’ll use table rates for shipping .You can modify it with respect to your requirements.

At last I want to tell you that this account specific FedEx shipping  rates we can’t show on your site because  FedEx shipping  system has some limitations, As it is a  third party site , we can’t access how much we need. So we can access those portions only, how much they’ll give access to us.

Kindly advise

Comment: Hello did you get any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

There are several options for you. Unfortunately Magento isn't shipped with great support for dimensional or weight based shipping, you'll ideally want to customize the FedEx api request and read through the WSDL & FedEx API documentation. In the Mage_Usa Module's /etc folder you'll find WSDL definitions. The Out Of The Box WSDL uses a slightly older version of the FedEx api than is the most current available. It is possible to swap out the wsdl file and re-declare the version if more functionality is needed.

Webshop apps 'ShippingOverride2' module is highly effective for creating the shipping price rules you're seeking. Also I believe in your configuration you'll want to turn 'ship to residential' to false.

Additionally if you're shipping calculations require custom box sizes, you'll need to add protected variables and leverage them in the API call, such as in Mage_Usa_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Fedex or your extension of said class:

```
protected $_customizableContainerTypes = array('YOUR_PACKAGING');
    protected $_customContainerSpecs = array(
        "LARGE PARTS BOX" => array("length" => 8,
            "width" => 14,
            "height" => 10),
        "XL PARTS BOX" => array("length" => 8,
            "width" => 20,
            "height" => 12),
        "WHITE BAG SMALL" => array("length" => 1,
            "width" => 12,
            "height" => 9),
        "WHITE BAG LARGE" => array("length" => 1,
            "width" => 16,
            "height" => 12)
    );
```